# Extracting data in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this array `const idArray = ["12", "231", "73", "4"]` and an object

```
const blueprints = {
  12: {color: red, views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}, {name: "top}, {name: "bottom}]},
  231: {color: white, views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}]},
  73: {color: black, views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}, {name: "top}, {name: "bottom}]},
  4: {color: silver, views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}, {name: "top}, {name: "bottom}]},
}
```

How can I return an array of the following objects that have all **front**, **back**, **top**, and **bottom** using ES6 `map/filter/some` and etc?:

```
result =[
    {colorId: "12", views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}, {name: "top}, {name: "bottom}]}
    {colorId: "73", views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}, {name: "top}, {name: "bottom}]}
    {colorId: "4", views: [{name: "front}, {name: "back}, {name: "top}, {name: "bottom}]}
]
```

I did it here but I feel like it is too messy and hard to read. Anybody could recommend on how to shorten it and make it easier to read using the ES6 functions (map, filter ...)?

```
 const result = idArray.map(id => {
      const bluePrint = bluePrints[id];
      const exists = blurPrint.views.some(view => view.name === 'top' || view.name === 'bottom');

      if (exists) {
        return {
          colorId: id,
          views: bluePrint.views
        }
      }
    }).filter(bluePrint => !bluePrint);
```

Comment: Questions on how to optimize working code are better suited to be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . You could use one `reduce()` instead of chaining `map()` and `filter()`

Comment: You have lots of missing quotes in your original array and desired result.

Comment: Another typo: `blurPrint` should be `bluePrint`

Comment: `bluePrint => !bluePrint` should be `bluePrint => bluePrint`, otherwise you'll just get an array of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ids so that [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) color in your target set of colors is in that id's `blueprint.views` and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) those ids to your desired result object:

```js
const idArray = ["12", "231", "73", "4"];
const blueprints = {
  12: {color: 'red', views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}, {name: "top"}, {name: "bottom"}]},
  231: {color: 'white', views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}]},
  73: {color: 'black', views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}, {name: "top"}, {name: "bottom"}]},
  4: {color: 'silver', views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}, {name: "top"}, {name: "bottom"}]},
};

const result = idArray
                .filter(id => {
                  const colors = blueprints[id].views.map(e => e.name);
                  return ['front', 'back', 'top', 'bottom'].every(s => colors.includes(s));
                })
                .map(id => ({colorId: id, views: blueprints[id].views}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map()` over your `idArray` to create the array in the desired format, then use `filter()` to test if `every()` required string is in the view array and filter out the incomplete items:

```js
const blueprints = {
    12: {color: "red", views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}, {name: "top"}, {name: "bottom"}]},
    231: {color: "white", views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}]},
    73: {color: "black", views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}, {name: "top"}, {name: "bottom"}]},
    4: {color: "silver", views: [{name: "front"}, {name: "back"}, {name: "top"}, {name: "bottom"}]},
  }

const idArray = ["12", "231", "73", "4"] 
const required = ['front', 'back', 'top', 'bottom']

let newArry = idArray
        .map(colorID => ({colorID, views: blueprints[colorID].views }) )
        .filter(item => required.every(direction => item.views.some(v => v.name == direction) ))

console.log(newArry)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(blueprints)
  .map(k => ({colorId:k, views:blueprints[k].views}))
  .filter(el =>
    ['front', 'back', 'top', 'bottom'].every(it => 
      el.views.some(s => s.name === it)
  )
)
```